# Is there midi software that can show me if I'm hitting notes on the beat?

Tags: practice, learning, rhythm, midi

I'm practicing phrases with a metronome and I can tell that my fingers are sometimes not hitting the individual notes at the proper time, even if the overall phrase starts and ends at the right time.

Is there midi software that can give feedback about each note I play telling me how early or late I play it? I'm envisioning loading a midi file and the software shows the score (or doesn't, that's just a nice-to-have) and then I can press 'record' and it will count me in with a preset tempo, and then record the difference between the midi score and what I actually play, showing it visually somehow.

Comment: You're already aware that your timing isn't spot on. Your ears should be the ones to rely on better than a printout, and even if you make the same errors each time, ears will tell you just as well as what you're looking for. Only my opinion, therefore not an answer!

Comment: I'm trying to rely on my ears but they're not very reliable, hence my desire to train my ears and my fingers with feedback from real-time data showing me just how off I am.

Comment: Your ears & fingers will not be trained by trying to compensate for any kind of 'block on a grid' visual feedback system that is already over & done with before it appears on screen. Music is done by 'feel' not by 'whack-a-mole' or scraping flies off a windscreen like some kind of Mavis Beacon typing tutor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - any sequencer program with an Edit window that displays note-on times.   Record yourself playing to its click, despair at your inaccuracy!   We've all done it.

If you want a more musical test, set up a drum track with a suitable groove and play to that.

Quirks of the system may cause your recorded notes to have a constant offset from the 'grid'.  But it should be easy to distinguish this from inaccurate playing.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a midi file of the exact arrangement you wanna play?  Then, yeah, most any midi sequencer.

But a better way is to just record yourself with your phone.  Not the whole dang song.  Cuz you're not playing the whole dang song, riiiiight?  Just the spots you have problems with.  How do you find those?  Recoooord yourself with your phone :)

Your ears will tell you if your rhythm is solid.  But, you're right - while you're going time and your brain WILL play tricks on your judgement.  Hence the phone.