# Software to sync with tempo in violin

Tags: violin, tempo

I am a beginner in violin (about 2 month) and i have trouble with syncing my tempo with metronome.
Beside the fact that thinking about everything makes me lose tempo, I use my phone as metronome and because of the volume of instrument itself I barely hear metronome beats.

I was thinking is there any software (or other technique) to help with that? for example a software being able to show notes with duration notations which I can visually validate myself?

Comment: If you put the violin away for a moment, can you _sing_ the rhythms in tempo without going out of sync? Just the rhythms, if you disregard the pitch aspect and everything about operating the violin.

Comment: See also: [Is there midi software that can show me if I'm hitting notes on the beat?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/75580/70803).

Comment: Do you want to see the notes you play, or do you want to see if you managed to play the displayed notes? I made a program for the first variant, but it had issues detecting the correct pitch so I think the second option might be more useful.

Answer (score 7):

If you want something which is like your phone app metronome only louder then the best thing is a separate dedicated digital metronome.The volume on mine can be turned up painfully high.

If you want something more visual then an old fashioned metronome is best where you can see an actual thin stick moving back and forwards at the set rhythm.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is actually very simple. If you like your phone’s metronome simply:

1. Connect your phone to an external speaker. Smaller inexpensive wired or Bluetooth speakers are available for a very reasonable price.
2. Use a pair of open air headphones or use a single earbud placed loosely in your ear so you can hear both the click and your instrument clearly.

As for the software you speak of that shows note durations in real time, software recommendations are off topic on this site but most DAW’s (digital audio workstation software) can show a piano roll with real time notes and durations. The only issue is the desired music has to be either programmed or found and downloaded online in MIDI format.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not a mechanic issue, but the lack of internalizing the tempo.

Are you able to do any sort of rhythmic activity with the music? (Dance, tap your feet/fingers, bob head, etc.) You actually need to learn to internalize the rhythm. A metronome is only one tool to do this, and ultimately no skilled player ever plays music with the metronome blasting.

Although using the metronome is useful, it may not necessarily be needed as an adult. You have been exposed to music before, and with different context. If you can walk in beat with music, or exercise with music and change pace according to what you hear, then you probably can try forgoing the metronome and simply internalize the beat instead.